# How can I use three fingers to drag on the touchpad of a MacBook Pro?

Tags: unity, 14.04, touchpad, macbook, gestures

I have a MacBook Pro running Ubuntu 14.04, with Unity on it. By default, Unity has a three-finger gesture that invokes the Alt-Tab launcher. But I really like the OS X-style three-finger drag gesture.

Is there any way to override the default settings and use the gesture from OS X?

Comment: I haven't tried it much as I use kde as a rule, but try easystroke: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/wiki they seem to have support for many different gestures and fully supports the apple trackpad.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, 3 finger drag does not equal to 3 finger gestures. When you do a 3 finger drag the pointer moves with your fingers, but when you do a 3 finger gesture the pointer remains in the same place.

I have done some modifications to the Synaptics Xorg driver to add support for 3-finger drag in Xubuntu:
https://github.com/quadpixels/three-finger-dragging

This is a video showing how it works ...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eLSEtibfyw

And unfortunately you have to compile it from source ...

Note: this is only for my personal test, it comes without any warranty.
I have tested it only on a Magic Trackpad, but I think it should also work with MacBook's trackpad.

:)

Comment: It works like a charm! One comment,  I use ubuntu on macbook as of recently and the three-finger-drag was the only thing I missed (ans spent good deal of time finding how to fix). The only small caveat was that by default ./configure; make; sudo make install installs the driver in /usr/local/libs/xorgs/modules/input , and X loads it from /usr/libs/....  Renaming the old drivers to .old and symlinking to the new ones fixed that :). Thanks for this!

Comment: That's a great work! I incorporated your changes into: https://github.com/sencer/synaptics which is a newer version (1.8.99), but SHM is NOT removed for use with multitouch stuff like xSwipe.

Answer (score 3):

From Ububtu 13.04 seems to be possible to use [touchegg package](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/)

There's one reference you can find interesting [OS X-like multitouch gestures for Macbook Pro running Ubuntu](http://ineed.coffee/1068/os-x-like-multitouch-gestures-for-macbook-pro-running-ubuntu-12-10/) about how to disable Unity default multitouch gestures and bring in OS X like touchpad gestures.

Comment: I really don't want to have to recompile anything (even though I am a developer), but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome... but you didn't ask for a simple solution :-) It's seems they will give such level of customization in the next generation of Unity: in the meantime... it seems you need to  experience it first-hand or use only 2 fingers ;-)